# What is the difference between :find and :edit

Tags: find, edit

`:find` and `:edit` both edit files and appear to need the relative or absolute path provided if the file isn't in the current directory.  What is the extra part that `:find` brings?  What is `'path'`?

Help for `:find`:

> :fin[d][!] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
>                           Find {file} in 'path' and then :edit it.
>                           {not in Vi} {not available when the +file_in_path
>                           feature was disabled at compile time}

Help for `:edit`:

> :e[dit] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
>                           Edit {file}.
>                           This fails when changes have been made to the current
>                           buffer, unless 'hidden' is set or 'autowriteall' is
>                           set and the file can be written.
>                           Also see ++opt and +cmd.
>                           {Vi: no ++opt}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `:find` will actually *search* for a file by that name in the list of directories specified in [`'path'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27path%27).

The default `'path'` contains `.` (which is the path of the *current* file), then `/usr/include` (on Unix platforms, like Linux and Mac OS) and then an "empty" entry, corresponding to the current directory.

Which means if you're editing `src/main/main.c` and you use `:find args.c`, Vim will first search for it in `src/main/`, which makes the default useful when you open many files in the same directory.

You notice your file includes `<stdio.h>` and you would like to open this header file, then `:find stdio.h` will find that in the system include directory. (An especially useful shortcut to this one is [`gf`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gf), which will `:find` the file name under the cursor, also using `'path'`.)

Finally, if you use a path relative to the current directory, one that will work with `:edit`, it will also work with `:find`.

---

And the behavior of `:find` can be easily customized, by changing `'path'` to a setting that's more appropriate for your filetype (programming language) and specific project, to make it really easy to navigate between related files and browse files in a runtime's standard library.

To give you some ideas of how powerful `'path'` can be, consider these settings:

```
:set path=.git/..;
```

This will traverse *up* the tree, trying to find a `.git` directory, then use the parent of that directory. In other words, this simple expression will look for the root of your git checkout and allow you to use `:find` to access paths relative to this directory.

Another powerful example is:

```
:set path=**
```

Which will traverse *down* the tree and allow you to open a file under any subdirectory in the tree. (Note that you should *avoid* this setting, it's preferable to have `'path'` set in a semantically appropriate way for your language and/or project, which allows you to quickly access *included* files following the same path search as the language.)

You might want to consider enhancing this experience with plug-ins, in which case some recommendations are:

- [apathy.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy): Set `'path'` and friends for languages such as C, Python, JavaScript and Go.
- [projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist): Understands your project's paths and sets `'path'` appropriately.
- Other language-specific plug-ins, such as [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) for the Ruby language.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  I missed the fact that `'path'` in the manual was a link to where it's described (new users: hit `CTRL-]` while on `'path'`).
`:find` is a powerful feature I wish I started using years ago.